# Using VBA, obtain the cell address of the output of a Application.WorksheetFunction.Index/Application.WorksheetFunction.Match

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(Motor.Table,     
         MATCH(R26,Motor.Table.RefID,0),
         MATCH("EPAct",Motor.Eff.Row,0)))
```

I need to find the cell address of

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngMotorTable, _     
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strMotorData,rngRefId,0), _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strMotorEffType,rngMotorEffRow,0))
```

Comment: `rngMotorTable.Cells(rowMatchResult, colMatchResult).Address`

Comment: What's the next step? You may need to use the cell (Range) object instead of cell address.

Comment: The next step is to use the address as the anchor for another range. That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much, Wayne